# Catalan numbers in functional languages

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sml, recurrence, catalan

The Catalan numbers satisfy the recurrence

[image: Catalan Recurrence]

Of course Catalan numbers have a closed form expression involving binomial coefficients. Also we can express C_n in terms of C_{n-1} alone. What I am wondering is how one can implement this kind of convolution in functional languages like SML or Haskell.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I do not even know where to start.

Comment: But equally, we don't even where to start in helping you.  Please be more specific in what's currently blocking you.

Comment: Take a look at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Catalan_numbers for a bunch of implementations and ask for specific problems you have with code you find there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can implement the catalan numbers in haskell (and I think as well the ml-family is powerful enough)!

But I guess this is not the answer you were looking for. So I hope you are familiar with the basic haskell syntax think of the catalan numbers as functions `catalan :: Int -> Int` any series of natural numbers is such a function (well for small indices). But as catalan numbers grow quite fast I will choose for the codomain of our function the type of `Integer`s(= arbitrary big integral numbers).

```
catalan :: Int -> Integer
catalan 0 = 1
catalan n = sum [ ?catalan magic? | i <- [1..n]]
```

I know I almost solved the problem but there is still the catalan magic ;-) you have to do on your own.

But before I stop a few caveats

- this version of calculating the catalan numbers is **far** from optimal or efficient
- the case of negative input values is not taken  care of.

Comment: p.s. another solution could involve the functions `zipWith`, `reverse`, `(*)` and of course `sum`

Comment: In Haskell, you'd probably just create an ininite list of all the catalan numbers. Assuming you restrict the type to `[Integer]`, that'd have the benefit of giving you memoization, too.

Comment: That's what I was intending to say in my comment - just less explicitly so that @Kuai can learn something